# Recursively repeat vector elements N times each

Tags: r

I want to repeat a vector N times but element-wise, not the whole vector.

For instance, I have:

```
v <- c('a', 'b')
```

Say I want to repeat n times:

```
n <- 3
```

I want:

```
vfill <- c(rep(v[1], n), rep(v[2], n))
print(vfill)
[1] "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b"
```

My best solution to date:

```
ffillv <- function(i) rep(v[i], n)
c(sapply(seq_len(length(v)), ffillv))
```

I am interested in fast & scalable solutions, for instance using rbind, plyr, etc.

Comment: Why not `rep(v, each = 3)`? Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: @AnandaMahto Exactly what I was looking for.  I have a somewhat complex objective function to optimize, built on "ragged" data.  I use the plyr split-apply-combine philosophy.  In the analysis process, I wanted to access some low-level intermediate data and combine it in a data.frame.  I learned one way to combine as I wanted to using ldply, but that particular way necessitated the type of expansion I asked about.  To your point, the way I am doing it may not be optimal!  I may have further questions in the near future about it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

```
rep(v, each=3)
```

or

```
rep(v, each=n)
```

where you have n defined